# Can we implement an interface in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, interface

I am just preparing for interview and I just came across this question :
**can we implement an interface in jsp?**

If yes then how can we do it?

I tried to find the answer on many of the site but not able to understand the exact answer for this.

Can you please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean like writing implementation class for interface in JSP

Comment: What do "implement" and "interface" mean in this question? Does it mean [`Interface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)? Or GUI?

Answer (score 3):

JSP are meant to reduce Java code and put more presentation (HTML)code. JSP implementing an interface does not provide any value. Who is going to use the implemented interface ?

[**SEE HERE**](http://www.coderanch.com/t/288655/JSP/java/JSP-implement-interface) .Here you can find some points

Answer (score 1):

You can import a class in JSP in which you implement an interface, or use Beans.

Answer (score 1):

Bad idea to put java program logic into a JSP - put it in a helper class (ie JavaBean) or tag library..JSP is not a .java so it cat not implements interface 
but you can use a javabean in a jsp and this javabean can implements interface

Answer (score 0):

As a comment indicated, in conversational context of JSPs "interface" often means user-interface, GUI. But that would be too trivial a question.

***Implementation of an interface***

```
<%
    List<String> roles = new LinkedList<String>();
%>
```

`List` is an interface, and `LinkedList` is an implementation.

```
<%@
    class ZeroMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {
        ...
    }
%>
```

As a JSP is a (to be generated) servlet class, of which the class name
officially is not known, for internal use only.

***Declaration of a local interface***

```
<%@
    interface A extends Serializable, Runnable {
        public int calc(int x, int y);
    }

    private A alpha = ...;
    private A beta = ...;
%>
```

So for internal usage possible in the declaration section `<%@ ... %>`. To collect several interfaces, as marker interface, and so on. As an internal usage requires an implementation, it gives *bulky* code.

So not really suitable for JSPs which one would like to restrict to the represation of results (View in MVC).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<%@page extends="bla.bla.bla" %>
```

or even

```
<jsp:directive.page extends="bla.bla.bla" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is NO. But you can declare a class inside JSP page.

Comment: A little more detail, such as an example, would be really helpful if you can? :)

Comment: This answer looks like a comment